# Elmah Log Error Timeout cause program to crash

Tags: c#, database, elmah

i am having a issue that my program potentially will occur many error(Example: read data from file, if data error occur the data should be recorded). I currently using elmah to log the error into the SQL database. The Elmah log error function to database might cause timeout and the program will crash. Is there any setting to increase the elmah function timeout or is my approach to use Elmah to log the error is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the timeout is current execute of the insert command, an extended timeout needs to be set through code. The only way (to my knowledge) to do this, is by forking the ELMAH code and setting this manually:

```cs
command.CommandTimeout = 1;
```

There is a connection timeout you can try setting through the connection string, but that is for connecting only and it doesn't sound like that is the problem here:

```
Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30
```

Comment: Hi, thank for answering. Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception(message)); and
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new Exception(message))); Is there any way to set CommandTimeout in this 2 function?

Comment: Not CommandTimeout, no. That value can only be set in code and that is inside the ELMAH source code. As mentioned, you can clone the code and insert the timeout yourself. But having a modified copy of the code isn't ideal. Maybe figure out why the execute times out? Must be a slow database connection, network problems, or similar?

Comment: It possible due to large table, currently temporary solution is to backup old record to another table. Thank for helping.